# JSP: Invalid encoded sequence submitting

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have an application based in the Spring 3.2.8 Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework

I have this JSP

```
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}" />
<form:form  commandName="niCincForm"
        name="niCincForm"
        id="niCincFormId"
        method="post"
        action="${contextPath}/niCinc/niCinc.do"
        htmlEscape="yes" >
```

But when I submit I got this error:

```
Exception: Invalid encoded sequence "%=request.getContextPath()%%3E/niCinc/niCinc.do"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this on the top of your page :

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```